# How to enable debugging on IRI?

Tags: iri-node, debugging

Once the user has installed a full node by downloading and starting an already compiled package (using e.g. [these instructions](http://iota.partners/index.html)), what steps can be taken to debug it?

For example, the [IRI GitHub page](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri) shows below sample configuration file with the "DEBUG" property set to "true":

```
[IRI]
PORT = 14700
UDP_RECEIVER_PORT = 14700
NEIGHBORS = udp://my.favorite.com:15600
IXI_DIR = ixi
HEADLESS = true
DEBUG = true
DB_PATH = db
```

I have a couple of questions that I would like to ask about this:

1. To get more information in the log file is it sufficient to set
   DEBUG to "true" if it is set to "false" and restart the iota
   service?
2. Or does anything else need to be done in addition (such as
   recompiling IRI with some specific settings)?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite undocumented and I read [here](https://blog.louie.lu/2017/11/15/iota-iri-configuration-documentation/): you also have to uncomment the debug part of IRI [logback.xml](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/logback.xml) file and then compile and package IRI again.